# What is the correct way to apply classes dynamically to odd/ even rows of Table TR element using Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, html-table, tailwind-css

Trying to alternate row colors in my tailwindcss styled page, the code below has no effect on my <tr>s:

```
<style>
    tr:nth-child(even) {
        class="bg-gray-50";
    }
    tr:nth-child(od) {
        class="bg-white";
    }
</style>
```

What am I missing out please?

Answer (score 22):

Add `even` and `odd` prefixes to your class list

```html
<tbody>
    <tr class="even:bg-gray-50 odd:bg-white"></tr>
</tbody>
```

See [First, last, odd, and even](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#first-last-odd-and-even) from their documentation

Comment: This is the correct approach and aligned with the utility-first approach of tailwind 

Answer (score 7):

As stefan.at.wpf mentioned you should extend your tailwind config like so:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  variants: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: ['even'],
    }
  },
}
```

Then you can use even in your classes in  like so:

```
<tr class="even:bg-grey">
```

Comment: The correct way for the example above is "bg-gray-50"

<tr class="even:bg-gray-50">

Comment: Note the from Tailwind 2.1 with JIT mode enabled you don't need to modify the config. All the utility function like `even:` are automatically available.

Comment: It should be noted that `odd` is also available. `<tr class="bg-white odd:bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100">`

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that you are mixing CSS styles and HTML classes. You have to go for one or the other. Assuming that `.bg-gray-50` corresponds to `#ccc`, you could apply the styles as follows:

```
<style>
    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
    tr:nth-child(od) {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

The Tailwindish way would be to use `even:someclass`or `odd:someclass`. Needs to be enabled first, see details [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#even-child)

Comment: Thanks for providing a reference. I wonder if that reference is outdated? I just went through the entire document and I can't see how to enable `even` and `odd`.

Comment: Odd and even are now included out of the box per https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/configuring-variants

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set kind of css classes into css tags.

Plus I advice you to set `border-collapse: collpase;` to your table, this way, you won't have the separation between your cells.

You must set css directly like below demo:

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    /*class="bg-gray-50";*/
  background: gray;
}
tr:nth-child(od) {
/*    class="bg-white";*/
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using @apply and then listing the tailwind classes you want applied to the element in question.

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {
    @apply bg-blue-50;
}
```